# Same query in mybatis and MySQL Workbench but returning different result value

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I need to solve a problem in a user following another user's follower lists (similar to the one on Twitter); when you open the page of someone, you can see if you have followed any of the list members.

This is the query I tried, when **#{uid}**'s follower is in **#{myuId}**'s following list, then ***statusCode*** != 0

```
select
        au.uid, au.friendId, ui.userDescription, ut.userName, ut.iconDir, ifnull(bu.uid,0) as statusCode
        from friend_table as au

        left join friend_table as bu
        on bu.friendId = au.uid and bu.uid = #{myuId}

        join user_info_table as ui
        on ui.uid = au.uid

        join user_table as ut
        on au.uid = ut.uid

        having au.friendId = #{uid}        
        limit #{page},#{size}
```

here are the results in MySQL Workbench and my mybatis project; the statusCode isn't returning  what it should be returning under mybatis

```
#{myuId} = 1
#{uid} = 1

-----------------------MySQL Workbench---------------------
uid, friendId, userDescription, userName, iconDir, statusCode
'2', '1', 'bbbbbbbbbb', 'testUser', 'images/100X100.gif', '1'
'7', '1', 'bcccccbbbbb', 'aaaaa', 'images/100X100.gif', '0'
-----------------------MySQL Workbench---------------------

-----------------------mybatis project---------------------
uid, friendId, userDescription, userName, iconDir, statusCode
'2', '1', 'bbbbbbbbbb', 'testUser', 'images/100X100.gif', '0'
'7', '1', 'bcccccbbbbb', 'aaaaa', 'images/100X100.gif', '0'
-----------------------mybatis project---------------------
```

here is the data in **friend_table**

```
uid, friendId
'1', '2'
'2', '1'
'7', '1'
'7', '2'
```

here is my mybatis version

GroupId: org.mybatis

ArtifactId: mybatis-spring

Version: 1.3.1

Does anyone know why it gives me an incorrect result instead of the result on MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Can you explain better what exactly is the problem? is the the query result? what is the current outcome and what did you expect it to be?

Comment: "MySQL Workbench" result is what I'm expecting, but in the "mybatis project" result is what I'm getting while putting the same query into a mybatis project, the difference is in the statusCode, just don't know why it is giving me a different result using the same query in the same DB

Comment: perhaps the statusCode is not mapped correctly with the column. the value 0 looks suspicious if it's the only value you always get in myBatis

Comment: just found out that  there is a minor mapping problem with a strange character in the class, somebody typed in "myuld" in the mapper for some reason lol

Comment: @LinkHe if you have already solved the issue, you can provide the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it was caused by incorrect mapping; make sure to have a good naming habit on names, avoid having a name like "myuId" or "myuld" lol